# Is it haram to watch tarot readings on YT just for comforting words?

Tags: shirk

I know tarot is haram and I don't believe it neither have I paid anyone for this service. I just watch it on YT sometimes because it's kind of an ASMR in hard times. They use comforting words that save me from anxiety and boosts me to keep working. They use the 'you will' phases that provides motivation better than motivational videos. Is it still haram?